# Jasmine error returning: Expecting an object to be returned when testing service

Tags: angular, jasmine, automated-tests, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am currently testing an add service. I am trying to see if the service is actually passing the model I am mocking. It seems to passing it which is great, but my one issue is that jasmine is expecting an object, not an array. When running the test I recive this error:

```
Expected '[{"userId":"1","id":1,"title":"test","body":"test"}]' to equal [ Object({ userId: '1', id: 1, title: 'test', body: 'test' }) ].
```

Now in my spec I specify that I am expecting an object too. My syntax is most likely the issue so and input would be great. Here is my spec:

```
  it('expects model to be returned,
inject([HttpTestingController, HttpService],
  (httpClient: HttpTestingController, service: HttpService) => {
    // We call the service


    service.add(dummyPost, 'http://localhost:4200/dashboard').subscribe(body => {
    expect(body).toBe(dummyPost)

    });
    // We set the expectations for the HttpClient mock
     const req = httpClient.expectOne({ url: 'http://localhost:4200/dashboard', method: 'POST'});
       expect(req.request.body).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining(dummyPost)); req.flush(dummyPost);


  });
```

the mock model:

```
 const dummyPost: Test[] = [
  {userId: '1', id: 1, title: 'test', body: 'test'},

];
```

This models structure comes from a model typescript class. Any help would be great. I believe the problem lies with jasmine expecting an object to be returned, not an array. If it helps, here is the service I am testing:

```
 add(model, url: string): Observable<any[]> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':
        'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
    let options = { headers: headers };
    let body = JSON.stringify(model);
    return this.http.post(url, body, options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using Json.stringify on my object.

```
 expect((req.request.body)).toBe(JSON.stringify(dummyPost));
```